# Is it possible to find the full view path of a model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

For example,

```
@foo = Foo.new
@foo.to_partial_path #=> '/foos/foo'
```

Is there some method I can use to find the full path of the file?

```
@foo = Foo.new
@foo.something #=> 'app/views/foos/_foo.html.erb'
```

I could infer it from the partial path, but the problem is that not all of my models are in my main Rails app. Some are within Rails engines, so their view path would be like `'engines/myengine/app/views/...'` instead. `to_partial_path` does not reflect that.

Rails has no trouble rendering the view when I am rendering from the controller. How do I find out what it is using to determine the path?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In model:

```
def self.Ping
  puts "#{__FILE__}"
end
```

---

UP1: Where Rails resolve pathes:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c19958015fac7b50f8dedbdf17991c00d6b8bbd4/actionview/lib/action_view/view_paths.rb

---

UP2:
*Rails has no trouble rendering the view when I am rendering from the controller. How do I find out what it is using to determine the path?*

```
Why need you doing that?
```

Comment: Can't use `__FILE__` unfortunately since I will be storing the method in a parent class, so `__FILE__` will return the path of the parent not the actual model. Thanks I will look into the view paths. As for why... does it matter?